# Why function is weightless?

Tags: c++

Why having function in my class doesn't change size of this class? This info must be stored somewhere, but where?

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Comment: By "size of this class", do you mean the size of the object file, or `sizeof(TheClass)`, or ...?

Comment: Learn to ask better questions. Like stating in your question what "fnc" is.

Comment: @Peter by size of class I mean sizeof(TheClass)

Comment: @Knowing: Neil wasn't the only one to wonder.  I *guessed* that by "fnc" you meant "function" (although what you're truly talking about is a "method", right?), but based on the terseness you could have meant something else, perhaps one of these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FNC

Comment: As it was written, Neil has a point.  `fnc` could be anything, including a function pointer would would change the size of your class.

Comment: @Knowing: You are not only obnoxious, you are also incorrect.  A method gets passed an implicit `this` pointer, and a function does not.  The words are different for a reason: they refer to similar but distinct concepts.

Comment: @Daniel:  In C++, "methods" are simply referred to as "nonstatic member functions."

Comment: @Daniel I don't think that you know the correct meaning of the word obnoxious, otherwise you wouldn't call me that name. And as I and James explained you are incorrect.

Comment: @James McNellis: Point taken.  I've always used "method" as shorthand for "member function" in C++ (and a quick Google seems to show this is common usage), but clearly my pedantry has failed. :-)

Comment: @Daniel I hope bit of this humble pie will do you good.

Comment: @All gotta go, but as usual those who downvoted didn't have guts to say it. Typical childish behaviour. Professionals my ass.

Comment: @Knowing:  I'm sorry, my impression (which clearly must be unfounded) is that your arrogance far surpasses Neil's.  But let's set the *ad hominem* aside and let's all just calm down, OK?  You got an answer to your question, didn't you?  No harm, no foul.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can think of a member function as being just like any other function, except that it has an extra, hidden parameter that takes a pointer to the instance on which the member function was called.

For example,  this:

```
class C
{
    void f(int i) { }
};
```

might be implemented (at least conceptually) as:

```
void C_f(C* this, int i) { }
```

If it was a const member function, then the hidden parameter would have the type `const C*` instead.  Note that the situation isn't nearly this simple for virtual member functions.

Comment: @Knowing: This information is statically linked into wherever a call to that method is used.

Comment: @Knowing:  There's no need for name calling here.  That's both rude and unprofessional.

Comment: @Knowing: The addresses are hardcoded by the compiler into the calling functions, there is no need to make it part of the object at runtime. In contrast virtual functions are only resolved at runtime and add a pointer to the virtual function table as overhead to each object.

Answer (score 2):

The `sizeof(TheClass)` is affected only by the data members within the class, plus the vtable if there is any, plus padding bytes if there is any. So adding a nonvirtual function to your class does not affect its size. And if the class already contains a virtual function, adding a second one would not change `sizeof(TheClass)` either.

Comment: @Knowing: The machine language instructions are stored in your executable binary file, just like they are for any other function in your program.  And if you think you're being funny with your comment, you aren't.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for your answer, and with with comment according to you I'm trying to be funny?

Answer (score -1):

Me think (and I tend to be wrong most of the time) that if you only declare a non-virtual function in a class but no implementation the linker will probably remove it all together.

```
class Toto
{
  int foo();
};
```

M.

Comment: Even if you had an implementation, the size would not change. The member function (if its non-virtual) is not stored in a class instance.  There is only one copy (ignoring static issues) in a program.